# Явное подключение библиотеки DLL С++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Всем добрый вечер, в общем пытаюсь разобраться с явной загрузкой DLL к проекту и столкнулся с проблемой. Программа не компилируется, а отладчик указывает на ошибку "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.__imp__GetProcAddress"
Выполнял по Учебнику Литвиненко и сделал по пунктам, а именно:
1)Создал саму DLL и прописал к ней def- файл
2)Библиотеку скомпилировал, ошибок нет
3)Библиотеку добавил к проекту
4)В сообщении WM_CREATE  получил дескриптор библиотеки: hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("")), передавая ей в качестве параметра имя DLL-файла. 
5)Функцией GetProcAddress() нашел дескриптор иконки, уже загруженной в библиотеке, передавая ей дескриптор иконки как текстовую строку: hIcon = *((HICON*)GetProcAddress(hDll, "hIcon")).
6)После этого изменил малую иконку класса окна SetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICONSM, (LONG)hIcon).
**Сообщение WM_CREATE**

```
case WM_CREATE:
    //получение дескриптора библиотеки
    hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("dllmain"));
    hIcon = *((HICON*)GetProcAddress(hDll,"hIcon"));
    SetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICONSM, (LONG)hIcon);
```

**В заголовка объявил импорт:** `__declspec(dllimport) HICON hIcon;`
**Содержание DLL файла:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"  #include "resource.h"  
    __declspec(dllexport) HICON hIcon;
BOOL APIENTRY dllmain(HMODULE hModule, //дескриптор библиотеки
    DWORD u1_reason_for_call, //код уведомления
    LPVOID lpReserved //зарезеврировано
)
{
    switch (u1_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hIcon = LoadIcon(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        DestroyIcon(hIcon);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Содержание def - файла**

```
EXPORTS hIcon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Вместо `LoadLibrary(_T("dllmain"));` следует явно вызвать wide char версию:
  `LoadLibraryW(L"dllmain");`
- Результат `LoadLibrary` надо проверять перед использованием `hDll`
- Результат `GetProcAddress` надо проверять перед использованием возвращенного указателя
- При экспорте данных следует указать `hIcon DATA`
- В `dllmain` ни в коем случае не следует вызывать функции вроде `LoadIcon`, вместо этого напишите и вызывайте три отдельные функции - `init_library`, `uninit_library` и `get_icon`, а сам `dllmain` не нужен.
- про name mangling не забываем
- Вместо `SetClassLong` следует использовать `SetClassLongPtr`, иначе указатели / дескрипторы будут обрезаться.
- Вместо `(LONG)hIcon` следует использовать `reinterpret_cast<::LONG_PTR>(hIcon)`

Comment: Добавил проверку, LoadLibrary и убедился к том, что компилятор не видит саму DLL не подскажешь в чем дело? Возможно ее нужно было как то объявить в начале?

Comment: @НикитаКолесников Чтобы узнать, в чем дело, надо вызывать `GetLastError` при ошибке. Ну и тут нужно убедиться, что библиотека лежит в папке с исполняемым файлом, и что битность 32/64 у них совпадает..

Comment: Спасибо большое. Проверил корневую папку с проектом, по глупости забыл добавить dll в проект. Снова скомпилировал код и все заработало, немного подправил в соответствии с твоими инструкциями и все заработало)